# Серверная часть сильно изменилась, как обновить приложение?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-games

Серверная часть подверглась изменению, что не поддерживает старый клиент.
Но поддерживает новый. 
Как в этом случае обновить приложение?
(Вопрос по гуглплей)

Comment: Ну, как обычно штатными механизмами обновления в Google Play?

Answer (score 0):

Выпустите обновление в Google Play Consol.
Но не забудьте:
1.Назвать пакет тем же именем
2.Подписать пакет той же подписью
3.Присвоить пакету следующий порядковый номер от последнего обновления старого приложения